# Calling SOAP operation with complex nested parameters in ActionScript

Tags: xml, web-services, actionscript-3, soap

I'm trying to consume a SOAP service that requires a number of parameters, each with nested properties.

For example the Send() operation takes "message" and "metadata" parameters.

The "message" parameter has a large number of properties, for example:

- "To" (Array of strings)
- "Subject" (String)
- "Body" (String)

etc.

I naively thought this would do the trick:

```
ws.Send( { message : {
    To : ["test@test.com"],
    Subject : "Test",
    Body : "This is a test."
} });
```

But when I look at the output through something like Fiddler2, I see that the <message> is just empty.

- Do I need to resort to manually defining my Operation?
- How do I handle the nested structure so that the XML that is sent looks more like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.webservice.com/api/1.0" xmlns:son="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DataContracts" xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">

    <soapenv:Header/>

    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:Send>
            <ns:message>
                <son:Body>This is a test message</son:Body>
                <son:FromAddress>from@test.com</son:FromAddress>
                <son:Subject>This is the subject</son:Subject>
                <son:To>
                    <arr:string>recipient@test.com</arr:string>
                </son:To>
            </ns:message>
        </ns:Send>
    </soapenv:Body>

</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Hey there, I tried to indent your XML to make it a little more readable. It doesn't look like valid XML because the `<son:     >` tags aren't closed. Could you please verify my edit and check if this is really the XML that you are using? I inserted a period after the list to get the formatting of the XML to work